# C++ openGL vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, opengl-3

When I was working on my openGL 2D platformer game, I noticed there was no color on my rectangle. So I thought this might be because of an error check I missed. Indeed I forgot to call the errorcheck function *facepalm* but this resulted in an error saying that my std::vector got out of index when creating it. I couldn't even start the program.

The function is called CheckShaderError, the place where the error occurs is:

```
    if (isProgram) {
        glGetProgramiv(_ShaderProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<GLchar> errorlog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_ShaderProgramID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorlog[0]);

        printf("Program failed to linkL: %s\n", &errorlog[0]);
        FatalError();
    }
```

//THE SHADERPROGRAM.CPP

```
#include "ShaderProgram.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ErrorHandeler.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram() : _ShaderProgramID(0){}

//Creates, compiles and links the shaders.
void ShaderProgram::Init()
{
//Create the shader program.
_ShaderProgramID = glCreateProgram();

//Create and compile shaders.
InstantiateShader(_Shaders[0], GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "Mesh/Mesh.vert");
InstantiateShader(_Shaders[1], GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "Mesh/Mesh.frag");

//Link the shaders after they are created and compiled.
LinkShaders();
}


//Creates a shader.
void ShaderProgram::InstantiateShader(GLuint shaderID, const GLenum 
shaderType, const std::string dataPath)
{
//Create the shader.
shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);

//Set the shadersource.
std::string shaderSource = ReadShaderFromFile("../2D Platformer/Shaders/" + dataPath).c_str();
const GLchar* shaderSourcePtr = shaderSource.c_str();
glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &shaderSourcePtr, 0);

//Compile the shader.
glCompileShader(shaderID);

//Check if the shader did compile.
CheckShaderError(shaderID, false);
}


//Links the program and the shaders.
void ShaderProgram::LinkShaders()
{
//Attach the shaders. the shaders.
int shaderCount = sizeof(_Shaders) / sizeof(GLuint);
for (int i = 0; i < shaderCount; i++)
{
    glAttachShader(_ShaderProgramID, _Shaders[i]);
}

//Link the program.
glLinkProgram(_ShaderProgramID);


CheckShaderError(_ShaderProgramID, true);
}


//Check for any compile or linking errors.
void ShaderProgram::CheckShaderError(const GLuint shaderID, const bool 
isProgram)
{
GLint compileCheck = 0;
if (isProgram) {
    glGetProgramiv(_ShaderProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS,(int *)&compileCheck);
}
else {
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileCheck);
}

if (compileCheck == GL_FALSE)
{
    //The application does not need any garbage collection here because the 
deconstructor takes care of that.
    GLint maxLength = 0;

    if (isProgram) {
        glGetProgramiv(_ShaderProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<GLchar> errorlog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_ShaderProgramID, maxLength, &maxLength, 
 &errorlog[0]);

        printf("Program failed to linkL: %s\n", &errorlog[0]);
        FatalError();
    }
    else {
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        std::vector<GLchar> errorlog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorlog[0]);

        printf("Shader failed to compile: %s\n", &errorlog[0]);
        FatalError();
    }
}
}


//Read shadercontent out of file.
std::string ShaderProgram::ReadShaderFromFile(std::string dataPath)
{
std::string shaderContent;
std::string currLine;
std::ifstream shaderContentFileStream(dataPath);
if (shaderContentFileStream.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(shaderContentFileStream, currLine))
    {
        shaderContent.append(currLine + "\n");
    }
    shaderContentFileStream.close();
    return shaderContent;
}
else
{
    printf("Failed to read the shader");
    FatalError();
}

return NULL;
}


//Enables the current shaderprogram.
void ShaderProgram::EnableShaderProgram()
{
glUseProgram(_ShaderProgramID);
}



//Garbage collector.
ShaderProgram::~ShaderProgram()
{
//Detach and delete all shaders.
int shaderCount = sizeof(_Shaders) / sizeof(GLuint);
for (int i = 0; i < shaderCount; i++)
{
    glDetachShader(_ShaderProgramID, _Shaders[i]);
    glDeleteShader(_Shaders[i]);
}

//Delete the shader program.
glDeleteProgram(_ShaderProgramID);
}
```

Can someone help me out fixing the problem?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question this did fix half the problem. Now the program does start and run but the program still doesn't log any errors (while it does not not link the program). Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It returns GL_FALSE, the error I get, happens when I create the vector<GLchar>

Comment: Please show the declaration of maxLength.